# Getting "too many arguments to function" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

So I keep getting this error only in the Visual Studio Code IDE, but not in CodeBlocks IDE, which makes me think it's not an issue with the code itself but something else? My terminal is configured to cmd. I was following a beginner video guide in C from freecodecamp.

Here's the code:

```c
void sayHi();
int main ()
{
  
    sayHi ("Mery");
    
    return 0;
}

void sayHi (char name[])
{
    printf ("Hello %s.", name);
}

void sayHi()
{
}
```

This is the error:

[image: Error]

I tried changing the terminal and seeing if I had any syntax errors, but I didn't see anything in particular that worked.

Comment: A function declaration should include the function's arguments.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I followed exactly as the guide says and this is my first day coding :(

Comment: Please don't show text in images. Copy-paste into the question instead. In your image, your file has the ending `.cpp` (instead of `.c`), which likely means it is going to be compiled as C++, not C. These are different languages and the behavior will be different. Which one are you actually trying to write?

Comment: Before you get to that problem, there is another one you must resolve first. You have included 2 different definitions  for a function called `sayHi`. Either delete one or change its name to something different. Compiler says: "error: redefinition of 'sayHi'".

Comment: Sorry I didnt realize putting it as an image would be an issue! I'll keep that in mind. I did fix it to a .c file instead. As for the definition, there's a second one there because earlier it had an issue compiling it, and put a new definition in for sayHi. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it

Comment: Depending which fcn you choose to keep, the proper C language prototype should be `void sayHi(void);` or `void sayHi (char name[]);`. In C, ``void sayHi();` is a forward declaration, but not a proper prototype as it does not specify anything about the parameters. (Aside: C++ rules are a bit different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you declare that `sayHi` takes no arguments:

```c
void sayHi();
```

Here you declare that it takes one:

```c
void sayHi (char name[])
{
    printf ("Hello %s.", name);
}
```

Inconsistent declarations is an error.

Also, you have a second definition for `sayHi`.

```c
void sayHi()
{
}
```

Multiple definitions for a symbol is an error.

Fixed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void sayHi( const char *name ) {
   printf( "Hello %s.\n", name );
}

int main( void ) {
   sayHi( "Mery" );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you!! I originally started with only one instance of a definition for sayHi, but then it said "Function not declared for this scope" when I went to compile it. So then I googled and one of the solution was to add a line declaring another definition, which temporarily fixed the problem. This makes sense now though, thank you sm!

Comment: In C, `void sayHi();` indicates unspecified arguments (unlike C++) and I would recommend not using that form. You need `void sayHi(void);` to specify no arguments.